# universal regex code

Tags: php, regex, xpath, preg-match

I am a beginner in web development especially in the regex code and want to know if it is possible to write a universal code that will retrieve the coordinates of the sites regardless of whether they are in the iframe code or image URL or in javascript.

```
<div id="g_map"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=key" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

//<![CDATA[

var html = '';    
var lat  = 44.799439;
var lang = 20.483494;
if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
{
...
```

second example:

```
<div class="map">
    <iframe frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title=""  
          src="http://www.kolektiva.rs/beograd/dailydeal/vendor/map/center/44.79848,20.473856/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Is it possible to first remove all the characters and all characters that were only the coordinates of the decimal point and so they take?

Comment: Yeah, we all want a "universal regex code"...

Comment: Forget regex. Use DOM tree or whatever else utility you can think of other than regexes for this task.

Comment: no, i want to remove all character and only stay coordinates and then is easy to use regex...

Comment: REGEX, I do not think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: in other word I want to remove anything else decimal number

Comment: What assumption can be made? (This is the most important part of regular expressions.) Things like know var names, url components and the like might make it possible. However, without some constraints I'd say it seems nearly impossible to differentiate between a normal float and a coordinate.

Comment: @JOJOJO and what happend when you have multiple decimal numbers? Which one you remove and which one you don't? And what happens..

Comment: Actually might be possible if the decimal precision is always the same.

Comment: I think that all this turns into a string to a cryptographic erase all but the decimal number that is actually the coordinates. is it possible?

Comment: only stay in string 2 -decimal numbers (first is latitude, socond decimal number is longitude)

Comment: Yes it is possible but it is fragile. This is what we are trying to tell you.

Comment: to write some php or JS function who will recognize decimal numbers and delete everything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First example**:

Evaluating the following XPath 1.0 expression:

```
normalize-space(translate(.,translate(.,' 0123456789.', ''), ' '))
```

**produces**:

```
44.799439 20.483494
```

**This can be done with any XPath engine and the context node must be the document-node, or within XSLT 1.0, as below**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "normalize-space(translate(.,translate(.,' 0123456789.', ''), ' '))
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document** (the same as the provided one, but completed):

```
<html>
    <div id="g_map"></div>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=key" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var html = '';
        var lat  = 44.799439;
        var lang = 20.483494;
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
        {}
    ]]>
</script>
</html>
```

**the result is**:

```
44.799439 20.483494
```

**Second example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//*/@src">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "normalize-space(translate(.,translate(.,' 0123456789.', ''), ' '))
   "/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces**:

```
..44.7984820.473856
```

and needs just a little bit more cleaning.

---

**II. More serious processing (XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0)**

**This transformation is really "universal" and works on both examples**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:analyze-string select="string-join((.,//*/@*), ' ')"
                         regex="\-?\d+\.\d+">
     <xsl:matching-substring>
       <xsl:sequence select="concat(., ' ')"/>
     </xsl:matching-substring>  
     </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the second XML**:

```
<div class="map">
    <iframe frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no"  marginwidth="0" 
             marginheight="0" title=""               
src="http://www.kolektiva.rs/beograd/dailydeal/vendor/map/center/44.79848,20.473856/">
</iframe>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
44.79848  20.473856
```

**when applied on the XML for the first example, it also produces the wanted result**:

```
44.799439  20.483494
```

Comment: Where to put string in first example and how to call in your xpath expresion

Comment: no problem but keep in mind that changes to the string is not always the same ... I want to pull any of the string decimal numbers just because they are the coordinates and no other number,

Comment: whatever string I need to get only decimal numbers, and possibly (-) minus if it is in front of the decimal numbers. Thanks in advance

Comment: @JOJOJO: I have updated my answer with a single, "universal" XSLT 2.0 solution :). Glad to be chatting with a Slav :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I interpret your question correctly. But if what you want is to extract the numbers 44.79848 and 20.473856 from the two snippets you have provided above (not varying much else than above) then yes, no problem.

The more generic you want it to be, the more less fitting I would say it is to use regular expressions.

I think you have to be way more specific in your question if you want more constructive answers that can actually help you.

Comment: Yes, you're right I want to make some generic code that will get from string decimals that there are

Comment: Here is example how i try: $string = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=186x186&sensor=false&markers=color:red|size:mid|42.052661,-88.049441'; 
preg_match_all('#(([0-9]+){1,3}\.([0-9]+))#is', $string, $matches); 
print_r($matches[1]); but I get this: Array ( [0] => 186x186 [1] => 42.052661 [2] => 88.049441 )... i dont want array[0] just [1][2] and how to get '-'(minus) with [2]second decimal numbers-coordinates ?

Comment: I meant to write \d+.\d+. Anyway, maybe it's a problem that will be solved if you actually learn the tools (in this case PHP) better.