# Decimal numbers from string with regex

Tags: regex, string, preg-match, decimal

I'm new to web programming, especially in the regex. I want to create a universal code that will extract decimal numbers from a string because I noticed that the coordinates that we should always decimal numbers and therefore pull out when I get decimal numbers and coordinates. What we're real problem is that some coordinates are (-) minus before the decimal numbers. How to solve this problem.

I tried with this code:

```
$string = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=186x186&sensor=false&markers=color: red|size:mid|42.052661,-88.049441';

preg_match_all('#(([0-9]+){1,3}\.([0-9]+))#is', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

but I get: Array ( [0] => 186x186 [1] => 42.052661 [2] => 88.049441 ) where array[0] unnecessary a minus sign is not taken to coordinate. Is there other way and is it possible to build this. (sorry for my english, is not very well but I'm learning hard)

Comment: I also like that this works and when you add another string ... means not specifically for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [universal regex code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932528/universal-regex-code)

Comment: No, its not duplicate... this is another question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match coordinates only, try following regexp:

```
(\-?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]+)(?:,|\||$)
```

Two first group matches will be coordinates.

Comment: Result is again same: Array ( [0] => 186x186 [1] => 42.052661 [2] => -88.049441 ) (array[0] is not unnessesary, but this time second coordinates have (-)minus. Thanks

Comment: and if i change string: $string = 'http://234234maps.google.com/maps/api/2344324staticmap?size=186x186&sensor=false&markers=color: red|size:mid|42.052661,-88.049441'; this code matches all numbers, I need to matces only decimal numbers

Comment: Then remove optional flag from decimal group: `(\-?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]+)(?:,|\||$)`